# how to use like percentage(like %) inside mysql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am working in python by retrieving data from mysql but its showing error as

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 101
```

the query written in python as below

```
adminperday = """SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM users where name like "%admin%" and date(reg_date) between %s and %s """ % (startdate,enddate)
```

its showing error near `like "%admin%"`.

Please help me.

Comment: Use singe quote like this '%admin%'.

Comment: @Ananth That's irrelevant.

Comment: FWIW, shouldn't you be using your mysql adapter's prepared statement interpolation feature instead of doing `%` string interpolation?

Comment: @AnanthCool: single quotes didnt help. tried with that.